# pytorch best way to call unique_consecutive() on certain dimension of a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

What's the best way to call `unique_consecutive()` on certain dimension of a tensor, and pad the left-out with specified values?
For simplicity, we could use 2D tensor as an example:

```
input = tensor([[3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
                [3, 3, 2, 2, 3]])
```

if specifying padding value -1, what i hope to get is:

```
output = tensor([[3, 5, -1, -1, -1],
                 [3, 2, 3, -1, -1]])
```

Also, to save memory, i'd prefer to do so in-place if possible.
Thanks!

Comment: `torch.unique_consecutive(input, dim = 1)` will yield a tensor with the following contents: `[[3,5,5], [3,2,3]]`. Do you desire to prune the last `5`, or was that a typo in your question?

Comment: no,  `[[3,5,5], [3,2,3]]` is not the expected result, what's expected is shown above: on each row, the same consecutive elements are collapsed into one, e.g., [3, 3, 5, 5, 5] becomes [3, 5], and then are padded with -1 to become [3, 5, -1, -1, -1]

Answer (score 0):

found a decent solution from PyTorch forum https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-way-to-run-unique-consecutive-on-certain-dimension/112662, quoted here for quick reference.

```
    x = tensor([[3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
                [3, 3, 2, 2, 3]])
    unique_x, indices = torch.unique_consecutive(x, return_inverse=True)
    indices -= indices.min(dim=1, keepdims=True)[0]
    result = -torch.ones_like(x)
    result = result.scatter_(1, indices, x)
```